# UTF-8 not showed correctly since updating to MAMP PRO 4.0.6

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have updated my MAMP Pro to the 4.0.6 Version from 3.x today and since then I am having the problem that my local site on MAC OSX 10.11 is not supporting UTF-8 characters anymore.

So I am having for example the "Ã¼" character in my mysql database which should show the "ü" character on my page but it does not, also when I am saving a "ü" character it saves it as a "ü" instead of "Ã¼" in the database.

I am using the mysqli class and checked with the get_charset function that the charset of mysql connection is correct (utf8_general_ci). 
Also the local database and its tables have the right charset (utf8_general_ci).

I also added in the php.ini:

> default_charset = "utf-8"

In my Apache http.conf I added the line

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8

In my HTML-HEAD files I have the following line:

> meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

Still the same problem, I am thankful for any help…

**EDIT:**
As Roland Starke and junkfoofjunkie said in the comments its totally right to save the values in the database as "ü" and not "Ã¼" (I did it wrong for a long time). It turned out that my MAMP 4 configuration was correct, but my MAMP 3 configuration was wrong. In addition my online version which runs on Amazon RDS was wrong and not configured in UTF-8 but in Latin1, seems like RDS always is in latin by default. I did what wtravish said to correct that: [Converting RDS database to UTF-8](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=574515)

I also had to change the content, the following sql-code helped me:

> UPDATE `table_name` SET
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'ÃŸ','ß'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¤','ä'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¼','ü'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¶','ö'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã„','Ä'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ãœ','Ü'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã–','Ö'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'â‚¬','€'),
>   `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Â°','°');

Comment: "also when I am saving a "ü" character it saves it as a "ü" instead of "Ã¼" in the database." -> Sounds good for me. (?!) Maybe you had a wrong charset before updating?

Comment: If you have `utf-8` set correctly throughout your website, it **should** save as **ü**, not **Ã¼**. So there is definitely something else wrong with your site. The "Ã¼" is NOT a UTF-8 character, it's an encoding of a character that doesn't work with the character set you have - hence I'm suspecting you either had a different encoding earlier, in the database, or in the files?

Comment: Thank you both, it seems I have done it wrong before, so actually its correct this way...

Comment: there's a surprising number of places the character set can be set wrong - not just in the tables and in php but in the connections between. try `mysql> show variables like 'char%';` and see if there are stray non-uff settings.

Comment: Search for "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Those `REPLACEs` are likely to make things _worse_.  After figuring out which case you have, perform the fix [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).

Answer (score 0):

edit my.cnf and put this lines on [mysqld] section:

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'

init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'

character-set-server=utf8

collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci

skip-character-set-client-handshake
```